# Live Server de VisualStudio Code no funciona

Tags: visual-studio

Tenia instalado live server y me funcionaba bien, pero me comenzó a fallar y  desinstalé totalmente. Después lo restauré pero el problema persiste.

Este es mi archivo .json en Advance Custom Browser Cmd Line:

```
 ***{
       "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
       "liveServer.settings.NoBrowser": false,
}***
```

Probé dando la ruta local de Chrome y nada. ¿Alguna posible solución?

Answer (score 0):

**¿CUAL ES EL PROBLEMA QUE TIENES?**

Si el servidor carga correctamente pero los datos no se muestran actualizados:
Activa el autoguardado

**Si liveserver NO abre tu navegador:**

Cierra VSCode (detendrá todas las extensiones que hayas instalado)

Luego vuelve a abrir VSCode, ve al archivo HTML que deseas ver, haz clic derecho y elige "Abrir con Live Server".

**Forzar abrir Chrome con settings.json:**

Toca F1, busca `Open Settings` y selecciona `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`, te abrirá settings.json y escribe `"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"`, guarda el archivo, cierra el programa y prueba de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso los datos no se mostraban actualizados cuando abria archivos desde mi ubuntu dentro de windows. Lo solucione instalando la extension WSL: Ubuntu.

Comment: Esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta... por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score -3):

**es la solucion de live server**:

es borra la confi archivo .json , lo que quiero decir con eso es borra las líneas de las configuración de archivo .json , al momento de borrar las líneas de configuración vs code se reiniciará.

pstd : vs code se pontra como si recien lo acabas de instalar :)

Comment: Por favor, corrige el formato y la redacción de tu respuesta. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._